# Need to UIAlertView show on current page and page not change

Tags: ios, objective-c

When I submit with empty textbox page is change and `UIAlertView` show after that, but I want to `UIAlertView` show in current page and page can not change (Stay on Signin Viewcontroller).

Thanks

```
- (IBAction)btnSignin:(id)sender {

    [PFUser logInWithUsernameInBackground:_txtSigninUsername.text password:_txtSigninPassword.text block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            NSLog(@"Login user!");
            _txtSigninUsername.text = nil;
            _txtSigninPassword.text = nil;
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Signin" sender:self];
        }
        if (error) {

            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"ooops!" message:@"Sorry we had a problem logging you in" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

            [alert show];
        }
    }];
```

}

My Storyboard : [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVRVU.png]

Comment: On a slightly unrelated note, its easier to create and display the alert on one line like - [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"ooops!" message:@"Sorry we had a problem logging you in" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22972483/login-failure-still-segues-to-next-view-controller

This is an answer

Answer (score 0):

You're performing the Segue with "Signin" identifier with the condition "error".

So when there's an error first your code performs the segue and then performs the error message.

Change "!error" with "user" and it should hopefully work. Let me know.

Comment: when there's an error the first condition won't get called so the segue won't be performed.

Comment: I see. You're right. Was not familiar with the "!" notation. Thanks for pointing that out. What seems to be the issue then?

Comment: It not work when error is the first condition and change !error with user this program not show Uialertview and still change the page.